# What are the other foundations of math?

Tags: foundations, philosophy

I know there are at least three foundations of math:

1. Zermelo-Frankel set theory. (Sp?)
2. ECTS
3. Category theory

Are there any others? Experimental foundations are welcome.

Comment: Euclid's elements was the first foundations of mathematics.

Comment: Re. 1, the spelling is "Zermelo-Fraenkel". Re. 2, it's "ETCS", "Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets".

Comment: If you're interested, you should also take a peek into the underlying logics and philosophies. For example, what happens when you reject excluded middle? What are the connections to category theory and type theory? Or in set theory, there are different approaches, like constructive set theories. All that stuff is pretty related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NF(U)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations). We don't know yet, but [Randall Holmes](https://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/) claims, that NF is consistent relative to ZFC. NFU is consistent relative to ZFC (and even BZC). But the category of NF sets is not a topos, so it's weird.

There are all sorts of variants of material set theory, some with non-classical logics, some permitting proper classes:

- [BZ(C)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory)
- [IZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel)
- [CZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Aczel's_constructive_Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel)
- [NBG(C)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)
- [MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)
- [IST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory)
- ...

There is also the structural set theory [SEAR](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR), devised by Mike Shulman as an example of structural sets not axiomatised by properties of the category they define.

One could also just take a dependent type theory, such as [Martin-Löf Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#Martin-L%C3%B6f_type_theories) (MLTT, but properly there are historical variants).

CCAF (Category of Categories As Foundation) was proposed by Lawvere, but didn't really take off. See discussion at [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9269/category-of-categories-as-a-foundation-of-mathematics) as to how it could be improved.

Comment: You can find a decent (and working) treatment of CCAF here: McLarty, C., _Axiomatizing a category of categories_. Journal of Symbolic Logic **56** (1991, no. 4), 1243–1260 (doi:[10.2307/2275472](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275472), [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183743812), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275472))

Comment: Also [positive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_set_theory).

Answer (score 2):

[Univalent Foundations](https://homotopytypetheory.org/), using Homotopy Type Theory, is another.

(More generally, I like [this quote by John Baez](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/feferman_set_theory.html#c029804): "[M]y opinion is mainly that people should try all sorts of foundations and see what happens.")